# Why aren't my NSViews in my NSWindow resizing when the window is resized?

Tags: objective-c, macos, nswindow, nsviewcontroller, autoresizingmask

I'm pulling my hair out trying to figure why my views aren't resizing with my NSWindow on drag.

Okay, here's my structure:

- Subclassed NSWindowController's View ***(Use Auto Layout Checked for window. Auto Resize checked for view. Window's View not hooked up to anything  in IB, should it be?)***

  - Various Buttons
  - Custom View  **(Auto Resizes Subviews checked)**

    - Subclassed NSViewController's View **(Auto Resizes Subviews & Translates Mask checked)**

      - Various Subviews **(Auto Resizes Subviews checked)**
    - Subclassed NSViewController's View **(Auto Resizes Subviews & Translates Mask checked)**

      - Various Subviews **(Auto Resizes Subviews checked)**

I'm adding each of these views to my NSWindowController's Custom View. This is the only relevant method in my file:

```
-(void)setActiveView:(NSString*) viewString{
    if ([currentViewController view] != nil)
        [[currentViewController view] removeFromSuperview];    

    if ([viewString isEqualToString:kFirstView]){
        FirstViewController *viewController = [[FirstViewController alloc]initWithNibName:kFirstView bundle:nil];
        if (viewController != nil){
            currentViewController = viewController;
        }

    }

    else if ([viewString isEqualToString:kSecondView]){
        SecondViewController *viewController = [[SecondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:kSecondView bundle:nil];
        if (viewController != nil){
            currentViewController = viewController;
        }
    }

    //Resize Controller to Window's size.
    [[currentViewController view] setFrame:[myWindowView bounds]];

    //Embed current view into Custom View in host view.
    [myWindowView addSubview:[currentViewController view]];


}
```

The setFrame to resize does work when I change views, but not when I drag to resize my window. As far as I can tell, because setFrame works when I change views, the only one that really matters (but isn't working) is the Custom View inside my NSWindowController.

Also, this is how I bring this window forward:

```
    myController = [[MyWindowController alloc]initWithWindowNibName:@"MyWindow"];
    [myController showWindow:nil];
```

Yes I've already tried in my initwithframe:

```
[myWindowView setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];
[myWindowView setAutoresizingMask:NSViewWidthSizable | NSViewHeightSizable];
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Try to use only one controller inside your window and put all other views into that controller's view. I am not exactly sure but iphone has an issue that UIWindow sends UI events to only the first controller in its children array. Your case maybe something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do this without *Auto Layout*.

**Try this:**

- Uncheck *Use Auto Layout* for window.
- Go to *Size inspector* and make *autosizing* to Your Views like this:

  [image: autosizing]

Comment: I was really hoping this would work, unfortunately it didn't. :(

Comment: @incarna Hmm.. It should work, maybe You can create sample project with this problem and send me it?

Comment: Your answer actually led me in the right direction: after messing around for a bit doing this for each of my views, I actually just put them all back to Auto-Layout and it just started working again. I wonder if it was a problem with Auto Layout itself?